# Writing Label Class Conditional Statements in ArcPro version 2.9.5

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a label class, which will simply display habitat classification (Annex 1) Codes and Descriptions in a map, where there is an additional classification (Annex1_2) I would also like this to be included in the label, however this should be excluded when Annex 1_2 reads 'n/a'

I've created the below Expression using python. However the n/a values are still displaying on my map and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong?

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
def FindLabel ( [Annex1_Code_1], [Annex1_Description_1], [Annex1_Code_2], [Annex1_Description_2]):
     if ([Annex1_Code_2] is "n/a" and [Annex1_Description_2]) is "n/a": return [Annex1_Code_1] +'\n' + [Annex1_Description_1] 
     else: return ([Annex1_Code_1] + '\n' + [Annex1_Description_1] + '\n' + [Annex1_Code_2] + '\n' +[Annex1_Description_2])
```